# Extract elements from python list

Tags: python

I have a python list that is of this format:

```
original_list = [
   {
    'label'   : 'A',
    'summary' :  data_out,
    'details' :  data_a,
        },
    {
     'label'   : 'B'
     'summary' : data_out_2,
     'details' : data_b, 
        },......]
```

For labels listed here. I have another list that is of the form

```
label_list= ['A','F','G']
```

What I need to do is to join the two lists together where I get a new list that is where the label in the original list matches the elements in the label_list; so in this case I would be looking for an output that is:

```
new_list = [
   {
    'label'   : 'A',
    'summary' :  data_out,
    'details' :  data_a,
        },
    {
     'label'   : 'F'
     'summary' : data_out_6,
     'details' : data_f,},
    {
      'label'   : 'G'
     'summary' : data_out_7,
     'details' : data_g,}]
```

I've tried a few different ways but I'm new to python and stuck on this part.  Thanks!

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: First I tried to extract the first label item such as:  original_list[0] which just gives the first set of elements such as: 'label' : 'A', 'summary', 'details'.  I also tried original_list['label'] which clearly won't work.  So I am a little stuck at this point.

Comment: Try using the answer given below with the modification I wrote in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Much cleaner approach using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

original_list = [
   {
    'label'   : 'A',
    'summary' : data_out,
    'details' :  data_b,
    },
    {
     'label'   : 'B',
     'summary' : data_out,
     'details' : data_b, 
     }]
label_list=['A', 'F', 'G']
d1=pd.DataFrame(original_list)
d2=pd.DataFrame(label_list,columns =['label'])
x=d1.merge(d2)
x.to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a normal list comprehension would do the job

```
new_list = [x for x in original_list if x['label'] in label_list]
```

Answer (score -1):

One-liner using list comprehension:

```
new_list = [x for x in original_list if (x['label'] in label_list)]
```

which iterates over all elements of `original_list`, and compiles those for which `(x['label'] in label_list)` is true into a new list.

Comment: This is clearly wrong. `if` statement should comes at the end in your code: `new_list = [x for x in original_list if (x['label'] in label_list)]`. P.S: I didn't downvote. I am just commenting on the error.

Comment: Thank you Bazingaa that is so helpful that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help! :)